# No New Extensions showing

Tags: wordpress, extension

In the section *Administer -> System Settings -> Extensions*, when I click on the *Add New* for the list of 'native' extensions there are none there. I get the message

> There are no extensions to display. Please click "Refresh" to update information about available extensions.

Even after clicking *Refresh* I still get a blank page. It might be sometime similar to this bug, but it is marked as fixed:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19090

If it's relevant, I also have a completely blank newsfeed on my main CiviCRM login page. It says:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

My directory settings all seem to be correct, and I am using the CiviMobile extension without any problems.

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.12 on Wordpress.

===

Update: it started working again properly. No idea why...! Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the same against civicrm 4.7.12 against Drupal and wordpress  - I do get the extension list - so I dont think this is to do with civicrm 4.7.12 -

May be please check if you have dropped the extension in the correct location also make sure your directory path is point to the correct location-

If nothing works try to clear your cache and try again

I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Unfortunately clearing the cache and resetting the directories didn't work.

Comment: I did tried against Wordpress with civicrm 4.7.12 - it works as excepted - so is their anyway you can reinstall or check some error message

Comment: As Ramesh said, check your extensions directory and make sure it's the same as it was.